# Page enableEventValidation="true" error

Tags: asp.net, postback

I'm creating a client insert form, in this form has a `<asp:HiddenField/>` named Id for save selected client id, but when I try submit form, it is on `Page enableEventValidation="true"` error, when I rename this `HiddenField` for any other Id, it's work

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Id" />
```

My form can submit success when I set enableEventValidation="false", but maybe I will need it in future

How to can I resolve this problem? keep `HiddenField` named `Id`

PrintScreen:
[image: error message screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question. The only way to make this work is set `enableEventValidation="false"` or rename your `HiddenField`

Renaming it would be the best solution here, for security reasons

Comment: Okey, but why I can't name "Id" for control? it is reserved word for asp.net?

Comment: I've actually created a sample app which has a Hidden field named Id and it doesn't cause any issues. There must be something else causing the issue when combined with this field.

Answer (score 2):

If you're are using framework 4.0 then entry in web.config ()

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you're using framework 4.5 then entry in web.config (requestValidationMode="2.0")

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client/34196133#34196133)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the solution for your problem, but i was having same problem and solved it by checking for postback before binding data.

```
  (!IsPostBack)
{
  binddata(); //this was my gridview binding function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when there is another form on the page that does not contain runat = server. Please check if there is another form on the master page or the current page.